# Memory of server never drops data of sql server

Tags: sql-server, performance, query-performance

I have this problem that occurred in one of the servers our System works in
the SQL server consumption of memory grows and grows until it gets 96% of memory
the system makes a request to the database but after the request is finished the memory still allocated that will cause server issues and delay of the system
don't know why the memory used grows way more than expected
PS : this only happen in one server only
the memory installed in the server is 256 gigabytes

Comment: It's not going to release memory unless it needs it for something else or it gets a memory pressure notification. You should just set the max memory setting properly

Comment: ya thanks now I understood the behavior of SQL server i thought it will release memory after the task complete